# Android Prorgram Crashes when i attempt to getText() from an autocompletetext

Tags: android, gettext, autocompletetextview

I am trying to build an android app that allows you to input text, and will then transfer the text to the main screen. It allows me to build the autocomplete with no issue, but whenever i try to invoke the getText() function, the entire program crashes. Any help would be highly appreciated, thank you

```
     public class TeamFragment extends DialogFragment {
TextView team1, team2, score1, score2;



    AutoCompleteTextView team1input;



public TeamFragment(View t1, View t2, View s1, View s2) {
    team1=(TextView) t1;
    team2=(TextView) t2;
    score1=(TextView) s1;
    score2=(TextView) s2;
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.team_score_layout, container);
    //mEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_your_name);
    getDialog().setTitle("Enter Team Name");
    Button b = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.teamButton);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            team1input=(AutoCompleteTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTeam1);
            team1input.getText();         //crashes here
            team1.setText("hi");
            dismiss();
        }
    });
    return view;
}


}
```

here is the logCat, I appear to be getting a nullpointerexception.

```
04-23 13:12:33.628: E/AndroidRuntime(902): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-23 13:12:33.628: E/AndroidRuntime(902): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-23 13:12:33.628: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at com.example.ucsb.cs.cs185.dimberman.nba.TeamFragment$1.onClick(TeamFragment.java:42)
04-23 13:12:33.628: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
04-23 13:12:33.628: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
04-23 13:12:33.628: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-23 13:12:33.628: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-23 13:12:33.628: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-23 13:12:33.628: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-23 13:12:33.628: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-23 13:12:33.628: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-23 13:12:33.628: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-23 13:12:33.628: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-23 13:12:33.628: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

`

Comment: You should provide the log cat. btw your implementation seems weird to me why do you pass View's as param to the TeamFragment constructor?

Comment: It's very likely your ``findViewById`` within ``onClick`` does not work since you put OnClickListener to a Button.

Comment: I was running into issues because findViewByID primarily accesses the main XML file, and so whenever I tried to access those from within the fragment, I was getting strange errors. I will add the log now.

Comment: upon further testing, it appears that for some reason, my findviewbyid is returning a nullpointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `team1input = (AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTeam1)` in the `onCreateView()` method and delete the similar line in the `onClick()` method.

(Assuming you have the `AutoCompleteTextView` with `autoCompleteTeam1` id defined in the `team_score_layout.xml` layout file.)

Comment: That worked! thank you! could you please explain why it work within the onclick?

Comment: Actually StoneBird has provided a good explanation in his answer. If you have any further questions, please ask more specifically.

Answer (score 4):

When you call findViewById() under a view class it finds child views of that class.

When the onClick is triggered, `View v` passed into `onClick()` is the button. If the AutoCompleteView you are trying to retrieve is not a child of that button then calling `v.findViewById()` will give you `NullPointerException`, since the view does not exist under the button's children tree.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
        team1input=(AutoCompleteTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTeam1);
```

with

```
        team1input=(AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTeam1);
```